# Branching git, running migrations, and keeping the schema functional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, migration, git-branch, database-migration

I'm fairly new to git and I've begun using multiple branches to build different features simultaneously using commands like `git branch`, `git checkout`, etc.

Here's a list of steps I've taken:

```
git checkout feature1
make some changes that include migrations
rake db:migrate
rake db:commit to feature1 with schema.rb

git checkout feature2
# at this point my schema appears to revert to pre-feature1
make some changes that involve a new migration
rake db:migrate
# schema now shows changes from BOTH feature1 and feature2.
```

The act of running `rake db:migrate` in feature2 refreshes the schema, which I imagine reflects my local database that underpins both feature1 and feature2. Do you know what I can do to keep these migrations separate so each feature can have its own schema, or is there another way to handle branched migrations?

Answer (score 0):

think about your workflow. In feature1 branch there is the schema.rb from feature1 but in case you used sqlite your database has been updated in feature2 branch. If you made changes in feature2 which breaks your application in feature1 you have to rebuild your database for feature1.

If you don't want to rebuild your database you have to configure your rails app to use a different database before running the migration in feature2 branch.

edit: Another possibility is to add your database to git (by changing the .gitignore file and adding it to the repo). Then you can revert your database with git.

Comment: It's not 'breaking my application' - after running `rake db:migrate` while in feature2, it runs just one migration but the schema is updating to show all four migrations. I guess what's going on is my database is not being changed to the different migration status each time a check out a new branch.

Comment: After running `rake db:migrate` in feature2 your database is at the migration version of feature2 even if you checkout feature1 branch after that.

Comment: right... so my question is how to deal with this issue most effectively. Reconfiguring/rebuilding a new database for each feature in development seems highly onerous.

Comment: I think i would copy the sqlite database and change the configure in the new branch to use the copied database.

Comment: It might be easier to keep a trunk with a clean db that gets copied into each feature branch upon branching (still outside of revision control).  I'm not a huge fan of SCM revisioning the DB unless you're planning on deploying it that way.

Comment: How do you keep your clean DB (think about SQLite)? You need to copy and reconfigure your rails app as i stated above. I would also like to know what is the easiest way for doing this.